# Curve25519 public key is 309 bytes and private key is 587. Shouldn't it be 32 bytes?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key, diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement curve25519 in my java program using bouncycastle, and this is the code I've come up with:

```
package crypto;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec.CustomNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.security.*;

public class Curve {

    public KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        X9ECParameters ecP = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("curve25519");
        ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(ecP.getCurve(), ecP.getG(), ecP.getN(), ecP.getH(), ecP.getSeed());
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        keyGen.initialize(ecSpec);
        return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    }

}
```

And my main method:

```
package crypto;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test_Curve {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        Curve curve = new Curve();
        KeyPair keys = curve.generateKeyPair();
        System.out.println(keys.getPrivate().getEncoded().length);
        System.out.println(keys.getPublic().getEncoded().length);
        System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(keys.getPrivate().getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
        System.out.println(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(keys.getPublic().getEncoded()), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
    }

}
```

This is the output I get from my program:

```
587
309
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
MIIBMTCB6gYHKoZIzj0CATCB3gIBATArBgcqhkjOPQEBAiB/////////////////////////////////////////7TBEBCAqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqYSRShRAQge0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0JgtenHcQyGQEQQQqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq0kWiCuGaG4oIa04B7dLHdI0UySPU1+bXxhsinpxaJ+ztPZAiAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFN753qL3nNZYEmMaXPXT7QIBCANCAAQrALerSrNmYi5/OYIDQo3cfvrxiMDTiNF9DrF7HEjIDgcwqTAxgznbdXo1eS4j6qK43enyCGRuD1gl4748Qjvj
```

However, this doesn't seem right to me. I read that curve25519 public keys are supposed to be 32 bytes, and this clearly isn't. I've done my due diligence and pulled several examples from google and tried them out, but still ran into the same issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to encrypt with a curve you may want to read into ECIES.

Comment: *"'I've done my due diligence ..."*.  Did you find and read the source code and look at the code that generates the encoded keys?  That's what "due diligence" means to me.

Answer (score 6):

Curve25519 is not an X9/Weierstrass curve. What you are doing won't be compatible with other implementations, which all use Bernstein's specifications for either X-only Montgomery-form Diffie-Hellman called X25519 or Edwards-form signature (normally without prehash) called Ed25519. The key encoding used by Java for all asymmetric keys (both public and private) is never just the key itself but [a generic encoding that includes metadata, either X.509 SPKI or PKCS8](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Key.html#getFormat()) and by forcing this curve first to Weierstrass form (for X9) and then to *unnamed* form by using the explicit and long-obsolete X9 form of `ECParameterSpec` you hugely bloat that metadata.

Instead use the *algorithm* `"X25519"` or `"ED25519"` in both `KeyPairGenerator` and subsequent `KeyAgreement` or `Signature` respectively. The standard encodings will still be longer than the raw key, but by much less. To get the raw key, in Oracle/Open use as appropriate the interfaces `{XEC,EdEC}{Public,Private}Key` which are implemented by the algorithm-dependent implementation (provider) classes. (edit) *Recent* Bouncy (1.65 up) run on sufficiently recent Java also does this; otherwise AFAICS you must get the generic (ASN.1) encoding and parse it -- Bouncy does expose that (ASN.1) functionality separately (through its 'lightweight' API not JCA) (and has since roughly the dawn of time).

Comment: Also, these values are needed for validation, right?

Comment: @kelalaka: I'm not sure what you mean by validation. You need to know which curve (and representation) a key is on to use it for any purpose, but you don't necessarily need to get that knowledge from the stored or transmitted key value if you know it by other means; for example Bitcoin uses bare points (in X9.62 format) with no metadata because Bitcoin defines they are always and only on secp256k1. If you mean validating that a point is on a curve, again you need to know which curve, but not necessarily from metadata.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 FYI, our (BC) recent versions include multi-release jars, in which the provider key classes implement the XEC/EdEC interfaces when they are available.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 It is strange that one transfers the curve into Weierstrass form to store. Also, since the curve is standard, actually one doesn't need to store the default values, instead just carry the name of the curve? This is not like RSA since the modulus is unique per private key.

Comment: @kelalaka: as I said, the code in the Q forces Weierstrass because of `X9ECParameters` and unnamed/explicit because of `ECParameterSpec`. The `{XEC,EdEC}` classes do use named form.

Comment: @PeterDettman: ah, I noticed recent bcprov are larger but hadn't got round to looking at it -- and my dev system, which is more convenient for source browsing that extracting the archive (or going to the repository), hasn't been updated for a bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to implement curve25519 in my java program using bouncycastle

My condolences.

Your problem is that you are outputting Base64-encoded ASN.1 instead of just the public or private key. [This decoder applied to your second output](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBMTCB6gYHKoZIzj0CATCB3gIBATArBgcqhkjOPQEBAiB_________________________________________7TBEBCAqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqYSRShRAQge0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0Je0JgtenHcQyGQEQQQqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq0kWiCuGaG4oIa04B7dLHdI0UySPU1-bXxhsinpxaJ-ztPZAiAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFN753qL3nNZYEmMaXPXT7QIBCANCAAQrALerSrNmYi5_OYIDQo3cfvrxiMDTiNF9DrF7HEjIDgcwqTAxgznbdXo1eS4j6qK43enyCGRuD1gl4748Qjvj) shows the actual private key. Note that the point is not compressed, so both X and Y coordinates are present (the two 32-byte octet strings).

Comment: it also contains the curve modulus, and possible fingerprint, too. If you wrote in detail this will be a good answer, too.

Comment: In fact the two 32-byte OCTETSTRINGs are (Weierstrass) equation coefficients a and b, the 65-byte OCTETSTRING is the basepoint, and the 520-bit=65-byte (after 'unused') _BITSTRING_ is the uncompressed public point; see the now-deprecated 'explicit' parameters format in X9.62 and more conveniently in rfc3279 section 2.3.5 (@kelalaka)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, I can see some, however. where is 9 of the base point of Curve25519

Comment: @kelalaka: the conversion to Weierstrass is an isomorphism and the corresponding point is different, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76641/how-to-impelement-mapping-point-curve25519-to-weierstrass-point .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that is the base of EC, no surprise there. The good point is the isomorphism doesn't involve too much arithmetic.